# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - sound only works after computer hibernate / suspend?

Tags: sound, suspend, pulseaudio, alsa, hibernate

Upon initial boot up of my machine there is no sound through the laptop speakers (however, using the headphone jack does work).  But after I do a hibernate / suspend there is sound through the speakers.

Before the hibernate / suspend the output is set to go through the speakers.

Is there a service I can restart (without hibernate / suspend) to get sound back in my laptop speakers?  I thought it was Pulse Audio's service, but I guess that isn't it.  From what I read about it Pulse Audio really just controls ALSA, but I don't know which service to restart, or even if that's really the problem.